# Find orthogonal matrix missing values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I was solving this problem, where I need to find the value *x*, which is missed in the orthogonal matrix A.

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
x&0.5&-0.5&-0.5\\
x&0.5&0.5&0.5\\
x&-0.5&-0.5&0.5\\
x&-0.5&0.5&-0.5\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

One of the properties of orthogonal matrix is that the dot product of orthogonal matrix and its transposed version is the identity matrix:

$$I=A.A^T$$

$$
A^T =
\begin{pmatrix}
x&x&x&x\\
0.5&0.5&-0.5&-0.5\\
-0.5&0.5&-0.5&0.5\\
-0.5&0.5&0.5&-0.5\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So I figured that $$x=0.5$$

That would result in identity matrix *I*:

$$
I =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

As the result I had to provide the sum of missing values, which $0.5\times4 = 2$. The grader (program) returned the error. Is there something I am missing (there most likely is, I guess)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Recall the definition of an orthogonal matrix $A$. Right, $AA^T=I$. When does this happen? For $x=¸\pm 1/2$. And are you sure that you have to provide the sum of all missing entries? Of $A$ alone, or also of $A^T$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde correct, they have asked for the sum of missing values. So I just figured the sum would be 2, but know when I think of it, Indeed there are two possible answers x = 1/2 or -1/2, therefore you can't give a definitive answer to the question stated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no they meant that there are four x values -> 4 missing values, if x= 1/2, 4*x = 2, elif x = -1/2, 4*x = -2.

Comment: No, since we have either $x=1/2$ or $x=-1/2$ it would be each times the sum of these four values $x+x+x+x$, so eight summands. So the sum is $4\cdot(1/2)+4\cdot (-1/2)=0$. Bu why should you give the **sum** ??  There is absolutely no motivation for requiring a sum. It would be ridiculous. Much more likely, the answer should be $x=\pm 1/2$, so both values as a **set** and not a **sum**. Which language is the homework? Can you give a link?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is orthogonal $ \iff x= \pm \frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: That is wrong; see my answer.

Comment: Thanks, edit follows

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* solutions: $\frac12$ and $-\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how you found $x$. If you actually compute $A^TA$ and compare with $I$, you get that $|x|=1/2$, so $x$ is either $1/2$ or $-1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

A short test is that $\pm 1=\det(A)=-2x$. This leaves both possibilities, namely $+1$ and $-1$ for the determinant, so $x=1/2$ and $x=-1/2$. Indeed, one checks that both cases yield an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone, indeed there are two possible answers $$x = 1/2$$ $$x = -1/2$$, therefore there can't be a definitive answer.

Comment: This is not true. Please show the exact question (whatever language), with a link. Only then one can judge whether or not there is a definitive answer. I suppose it is a misunderstanding. You are not suppoed to give the *sum* of all missing values.

Comment: "Sum" of missing values might just be "the missing values  gathered together", "in summary", or whatever. Not a mathematical operation $x+y$.